# Faster way to remove array elements with list of IDs?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to remove elements in an array using a list of IDs to remove.

```
const dataArray = [];
const idsToRemove = new Set();

for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
  dataArray.push({id: "myID" + i, value: i});
}

for (let i=0; i<10; i+=2) {
  idsToRemove.add("myID" + i);
}

const newArray = dataArray.filter(obj => !idsToRemove.has(obj.id));
console.log(newArray);
```

Result:

```
{id:"myID1", value:1}, {id:"myID3",value:3}, {id:"myID5", value:5}, {id:"myID7", value:7}, {id:"myID9",value:9}
```

Is this an ideal solution? Or would there be a more performant solution than this?

ADDED: Would there be a way to avoid making a `newArray` but just directly remove elements from `dataArray`?

Comment: The solution seems ideal to me.... also we can use `Map` instead of `Set` to store `idsToRemove` so that it's time complexity would  improve...

Comment: I found two solutions that are faster than mine: https://jsben.ch/ld9op

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modern way of coding this (not performance oriented):

```js
const dataArray = new Array(10).fill(0).map((item, idx) => idx);

const idsToRemove = new Set(dataArray.filter(i => i % 2 === 0));

const newArray = dataArray.filter(i => !idsToRemove.has(i)).map(i => ({id: `myID${i}`, value: i}));

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: How does this not have loops? You have `fill`, `map` and `filter` all of which are shorthand for loops.

Comment: @Nick - Behind the scenes it does loop obviously. But this is a more modern approach of coding these stuff today if you aren't performance oriented.

Answer (score 1):

You can save some computational effort by preparing the remove list as an object with the target IDs as key:

```js
let dataArray=[];
for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
  dataArray.push({id: "myID" + i, value: i});
}
let idsToRemove={};
for (i=0;i<10;i+=2) idsToRemove["myID"+i]=1;
var filtered=dataArray.filter(o=>!idsToRemove[o.id]);   
console.log(filtered);
```